# When returning a list in the web service, I get an error only if a value is returned?

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, web-services, get

The list returns in api. I don't get an error if there are multiple values in the database. Returns to the list correctly. but when i get a single value i get error when using api.

Thats my code;

WebService1.asmx

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)] 
public List<AP_City> AA_Send_CountryCode(string us, string ps, string country_code) 
{ 
    AP_City menuclass = new AP_City(); 
    List<AP_City> menuliste = new List<AP_City>(); 
    DbClassSQL db = new DbClassSQL();

    DataTable dt2x = db.Doldur("SELECT * FROM AP_City where CountyCode='" + country_code + "' order by OrderNumber");


    if (dt2x.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dt2x.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            menuclass.Id = Convert.ToInt32(dt2x.Rows[i]["Id"]);
            menuliste.Add(menuclass);
            menuclass = new AP_City();
        }
    }

    return menuliste;
}
```

That's my class

```
namespace Deneme
{
    public class AP_City
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change following lines:

```
    menuclass.Id = Convert.ToInt32(dt2x.Rows[i]["Id"]);
    menuliste.Add(menuclass);
    menuclass = new AP_City();
```

to:

```
    menuliste.Add(new AP_City() {Id = Convert.ToInt32(dt2x.Rows[i]["Id"])});
```

And delete the line:

```
    AP_City menuclass = new AP_City();
```